# Variable-Length Argument List passing generics and generic arrays as params - Java

Tags: java, generics, arguments, variable-length

I am attempting to write a helper print method so I can print items out to the console with less code and in an easier fashion.

I am however, running into issues printing arrays that are passed into my method because I cannot loop over a regular generic variable (E), but I am not seeing a way to fix it without possibly overloading the method.

Why does looping not work in my instance when I check that the variable is an array of generic type? I feel like this should at least allow a cast to an array (which is what the commented code shows now), but that fails too, which makes me think a cast from E to E[] is not possible in Java.

**Here is my code:**

```
@SafeVarargs@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")//SAFE
public static <E> void print(E... toPrint){
    //USED TO ENHANCE SYSTEM.OUT.PRINTLN AND MAKE EASIER TO TYPE
    E[] itemArray;
    for(E item: toPrint){
        if(item.getClass().isArray()){//IS ARRAY
            //System.out.println(item.getClass());
            //itemArray = (E[]) item;//WILL NOT WORK, CANNOT CONVERT
            ////IF LOOP ITEM ERROR NOT ITERABLE, BUT IT IS ARRAY?
            //for(E innerItem: itemArray)
                //System.out.println(innerItem);
        }else{
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated code based on @Sweeper's Suggestion:**

```
@SafeVarargs//SAFE
public static <E> void print(E... toPrint){
    //USED TO ENHANCE SYSTEM.OUT.PRINTLN AND MAKE EASIER TO TYPE

    for(E item: toPrint){
        if(item.getClass().isArray()){//IF IS ARRAY
            printHelperForArrays(item);//MUST CHECK IF PRIMITIVE[] OR OBJECT[] 
        }else if (item instanceof List){//IF ITEM IS LIST
            String[] stringArray = item.toString()
                    .replace("[","")//REMOVE [
                    .replace("]","")//REMOVE ]
                    .split(", ");//TURN TO ARRAY
            for(String innerItem: stringArray)
                System.out.println(innerItem);//NOW PRINT EVERYTHING OUT
        }else{
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }//END FOR
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")//SAFE
public static <E> void printHelperForArrays(E item){
    //USED TO PRINT OUT ARRAY ELEMENTS
    if(item.getClass() == int[].class){//IS INT[]

        String[] stringArray = Arrays.toString((int[])item)
             .replace("[","")//REMOVE [
             .replace("]","")//REMOVE ]
            .split(", ");//TURN TO ARRAY

        for(String innerItem: stringArray)
            System.out.println(innerItem);//NOW PRINT EVERYTHING

    }else if(item.getClass() == double[].class){//IS DOUBLE[]

         String[] stringArray = Arrays.toString((double[])item)
            .replace("[","")//REMOVE [
            .replace("]","")//REMOVE ]
            .split(", ");//TURN TO ARRAY

            for(String innerItem: stringArray)
                System.out.println(innerItem);//NOW PRINT EVERYTHING OUT

    }else if(item.getClass() == float[].class){//IS FLOAT[]

        String[] stringArray = Arrays.toString((float[])item)
            .replace("[","")//REMOVE [
            .replace("]","")//REMOVE ]
            .split(", ");//TURN TO ARRAY

        for(String innerItem: stringArray)
            System.out.println(innerItem);//NOW PRINT EVERYTHING OUT

    }else if(item.getClass() == char[].class){//IS CHAR[]

        String[] stringArray = Arrays.toString((char[])item)
            .replace("[","")//REMOVE [
            .replace("]","")//REMOVE ]
            .split(", ");//TURN TO ARRAY

        for(String innerItem: stringArray)
            System.out.println(innerItem);//NOW PRINT EVERYTHING OUT

    }else if(item.getClass() == boolean[].class){//IS BOOLEAN[]

        String[] stringArray = Arrays.toString((boolean[])item)
            .replace("[","")//REMOVE [
            .replace("]","")//REMOVE ]
            .split(", ");//TURN TO ARRAY

        for(String innerItem: stringArray)
            System.out.println(innerItem);//NOW PRINT EVERYTHING OUT

    }else if(item.getClass() == byte[].class){//IS BYTE[]

        String[] stringArray = Arrays.toString((byte[])item)
            .replace("[","")//REMOVE [
            .replace("]","")//REMOVE ]
            .split(", ");//TURN TO ARRAY

        for(String innerItem: stringArray)
            System.out.println(innerItem);//NOW PRINT EVERYTHING OUT

    }else if(item.getClass() == short[].class){//IS SHORT[]

        String[] stringArray = Arrays.toString((short[])item)
            .replace("[","")//REMOVE [
            .replace("]","")//REMOVE ]
            .split(", ");//TURN TO ARRAY

        for(String innerItem: stringArray)
            System.out.println(innerItem);//NOW PRINT EVERYTHING OUT

    }else if(item.getClass() == long[].class){//IS LONG[]

        String[] stringArray = Arrays.toString((long[])item)
            .replace("[","")//REMOVE [
            .replace("]","")//REMOVE ]
            .split(", ");//TURN TO ARRAY

        for(String innerItem: stringArray)
            System.out.println(innerItem);//NOW PRINT EVERYTHING OUT

    }else{//IS OBJECT[] LIKE INTEGER[], STRING[], CHARACTER[]... SO E[] WORKS

        String[] stringArray = Arrays.toString((E[])item)
            .replace("[","")//REMOVE [
            .replace("]","")//REMOVE ]
            .split(", ");//TURN TO ARRAY

            for(String innerItem: stringArray)
                System.out.println(innerItem);//NOW PRINT EVERYTHING OUT
    }

}
```

Passed Args:

```
int[] int1 = {4, 5, 6};
Integer[] Integer2 = {7, 8, 9};

double[] double3 = {10.01, 11.01, 12.01};
Double[] Double4 = {13.01, 14.01, 15.01};

char[] char5 = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
Character[] Character6 = {'D', 'E', 'F'};

float[] float7 = {1.999f, 2.999f};
Float[] Float8 = {3.999f, 4.999f};

LinkedList<String> listOfStrings = new LinkedList<>();
listOfStrings.add("List Item 1");
listOfStrings.add("List Item 2");

//CALLED AS
print(1, 2, 3, "Hello", int1, Integer2, double3, 
    Double4, char5, Character6, float7, Float8, listOfStrings);
```

Output

```
1
2
3
Hello
4
5
6
7
8
9
10.01
11.01
12.01
13.01
14.01
15.01
A
B
C
D
E
F
1.999
2.999
3.999
4.999
List Item 1
List Item 2
```

Now everything prints on its own line whether it is a primitive, an element in a Wrapper class, an array, a list, or whatever.

Comment: You cannot use the same parameter as of a type and as of that type's array type: if `E` is an array type, then it cannot be `E[]`... Right?

Comment: Yeah, that makes perfect sense, but the call **if(item.getClass().isArray())** only looks for items that are classified as arrays...For example in the code I posted I commented out the issues with arrays, but if you simply take out the conditional and write **System.out.println(item);**, you are given a memory reference so the actual array contents can never be printed. You can pass E[] to this method without issue too, which seems odd logically but with generics that is possible because it is a generic type

Comment: @ViaTech If you pass a primitive array, `E` will be inferred to be the array type. If you pass a `T[]` where `T` is a reference type, `E` will be inferred to be `T`. Primitives just can't be generic types. You have to overload the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you are trying to cast an array type `E` to an array of arrays - `E[]`.

If the execution goes into the if statement, that mean `E` is an array type. So `E[]` is an array of arrays. `E[]` and `E` are unrelated types.

So you need to some how let the compiler know that you are sure that `E` is an array and it can be looped over. However, there is no way to do that in Java.

So yeah, you need to overload `print`. This technique is widely used in the standard library. Just look in the [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class, almost every method there has overloads for all kinds of arrays. Java arrays have many limitations that you have to live with.

By the way, do you know there is a handy method called `Arrays.toString`? It can simplify your array printing process:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Maybe you don't need your `print` after all.

Note:

Your code works, just not for primitive type arrays, so if you pass in a `Integer[]` it will print it out successfully.

Edit:

You could work around this problem by checking the type against each type of primitive array:

```
public static void print(Object... toPrint) {
    for (Object item : toPrint) {
        if (item.getClass() == int[].class) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString((int[])item));
        } else if (item.getClass() == double[].class) { // check for all primitive types
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString((double[])item));
        } else if (item instanceof Object[]){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString((Object[])item));
        } else {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well my print method does enhance the standard **System.out.println();** method because it is shorter and now allows as many 'single' generic arguments to be passed as I need (i.e. int and String), but if you are saying that converting E to E[] is impossible that is starting to seem right, but in my above instance how would you overload the method to allow arrays to be printed still using generics? I feel there is an issue here because my original signature is still called when an array is passed as a parameter, thus calling **public static <E> void print(E[]... toPrint)** would not work

Comment: @ViaTech So you want to call it with arrays and other things mixed together as parameters? Then you should not use a generic type for that, as Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn mentioned, using a generic type would mean that all the arguments passed to it has to be compatible with one particular type.

Comment: Hmm...okay that makes sense, but still unfortunate because that means there would be no way to pass **print(1, "two", arrayOfThree)**, and still have every element (even in the array) print from 1 method call.

Comment: @ViaTech my answer should work with that. Does it not? What error does it produce?

Comment: Okay cool no errors with the code you provided based on our discussion. I used what you wrote to give me the idea I needed to make the generic version work the way I needed. I will mark your answer as correct, but check out the updated code I put in my question in a few min.

Comment: @ViaTech Are you sure a generic type is what you want? With that you can't do `print(1, "two", arrayOfThree)`.

Comment: Check the code I updated @Sweeper, I can pass an argument like this: **print(1, 2, 3, "Hello", arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5, arr6);**

Comment: You don't actually need separate cases for each type of array -- as a trick, you can wrap the array in another array of 1 element, and give it to `Arrays.deepToString()`, and then strip out the outermost brackets from the resulting string

Answer (score 1):

If you write `public static <E> void print(E... toPrint){` it will requires all inputs are the same class (`E`). And call method like `print(1, 2, 3, "Hello");`
 will not work

You should change your method to `public static void print(Object... toPrint)`

And you're freely to cast `(Object[])item`.

```
public static void print(Object... items) {
    for (Object item: items) {
        if (item.getClass().isArray()) {
            Object[] objs =primitiveArrayFrom(item);
            if (objs == null) {
                objs = (Object[]) item;
            }
            for (Object obj: objs) {
                System.out.println(obj);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}

private static Object[] primitiveArrayFrom(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof int[]) {
        int[] integers = (int[]) obj;
       return IntStream.of(integers).boxed().toArray();
    }
    // Test for other primitives here
    //finally
    return null;
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to directly convert object of primitive array to `Object[]` so you have to convert it by `primitiveArrayFrom ()` function.

If you're sure that your input are of same type (that is you don't mix `String` with `int` for example, then you definitely should write overload version that accept primitive type). Otherwise, give above implementation a try.

Comment: This still produces a  **ClassCastException** when an array of any type is passed. The original code also will and does work. It would throw a few warnings because of generics but they are safe, so you use @SafeVarargs

Comment: I've tested it, wait a sec

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array` Wrapper class of primitive type `int` which is Integer will solve your problem.

```
Integer[] arr = {4, 5, 6};
print(arr);
```

Instead of :

```
print(1, 2, 3, "Hello");
int[] arr = {4, 5, 6};
print(arr);
```

Now, what happens when you pass `int[]` Array and try to convert it E[] it actually tries to convert into `Integer[]`. So, basically tries to autoboxing the array but only `autoboxing` of primitive type is possible but we can't `auto box` `primitive` type array inke `int[]`.

Comment: Makes sense @Amit Bera, I will give a +1. I did notice while coming up with the update I posted in my question thread that my issues while converting to E were only applicable if I was using primitive types. I think (or am pretty sure) these issues occur because generics are not meant to work with primitives in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#get-java.lang.Object-int-) to index an array without knowing its type:

```
for (int i = 0, len = Array.getLength(item); i < len; i++)
    System.out.println(Array.get(item, i));
```